# Use XmlSerializer Instead of DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer

So I have a web service that is configured using a webHttpBinding and a webHttp endpoint behavior. I want WCF to use the XmlSerializer instead of the DataContractSerializer, so I tried putting the XmlSerializerFormat attribute on my service class. When I do this I start getting a 400 response. Everything works when I do not have the XmlSerializerFormat on my service.

How can I make my WCF service that uses a webHttp binding and behavior use the XmlSerializer instead of the DataContractSerializer with minimal code changes?

If you need additional information about my implementation please comment and I will provide details. Thanks!

Comment: 1)  Is there an exception? If so, can you share it?  2) Could your classes be missing default constructors?  `XmlSerializer` requires a public default constructor to serialize or deserialize a class, `DataContractSerializer` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue turned out to be that there is a schema difference between the Xml generated by `DataContractSerializer` and `XmlSerializer` and because the client was still sending the Xml string generated by `DataContractSerializer` it was not being accepted during the conversion.